# How to run the .reg file using PowerShell with an application install

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to write a powershell script which will allow me to deploy the Chrome browser cloud management tool to windows devices.

I am able to run the script without any errors, the registry updates, however the program does not install the application.

This is the script I have

Invoke-Command {reg import "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\enroll_in_03pgbopr1t3ll4p.reg" *>&1 | Out-Null}

When I run this script, I expect the changes to be made in the registry and also for the program to be installed.

If I double click the file, it will install the application AND make the changes in the registry.

Any advice on how to get the enrollment file to install the application and add make changes to the registry?

Comment: You need to be a Admin.  Try right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Then run your script.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: As an aside: There's usually no good reason to use `Invoke-Command` for _local_ calls. `reg import "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\enroll_in_03pgbopr1t3ll4p.reg" *>$null` is a simpler formulation of your command, which, however, likewise _hides potential errors_.